# Pushing information from dictionary to UITextField (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, uitextfield

I'm trying to push information from a selected `UITableviewCell` student cell to an view controller with a `UITextField` for each part of information   (first name, last name, etc) so it can be changed but I can not seem find how to push that info from the dictionary to each text field. I've tried reassigning it with no luck.

**Here is my a sample of my dictionary swift file**

```
class ClassRosterModel {

//Student Dictionary for Student infomation
var studentsRoster = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

init () {

    studentsRoster.append(["firstName": "Alex" , "lastName" : "Kaz", "major" : "SE", "email" : "s123456@school.edu", "currentTerm" : "Spring", "numberOfCredits" : "\(randomCredits[0])", "password" : "000000"])

}
```

And here is part of my class that has all the cells before selecting 
with the segue

```
class ClassRosterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//declaring studentsList dictionary
var studentsList = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

var selectedRowIndex = 0



    //Assignment of studentsList and myStudentRoster
    let myStudentRoster = ClassRosterModel()
    studentsList = myStudentRoster.studentsRoster



//declaring cell with identifier from studentCell.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configuring the cell with student information
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(studentsList[indexPath.row]["lastName"]!), \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["firstName"]!) - \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["email"]!)"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(studentsList[indexPath.row]["currentTerm"]!) - \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["numberOfCredits"]!) credits"


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! StudentInfoViewController

    let selectedStudent = studentsList[selectedRowIndex]

    dvc.studentRecord = selectedStudent

}
```

And I just made the text field for the first name in the 
student info page

```
class StudentInfoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var FirstNameTextField: UITextField!

var studentRecord = Dictionary<String, String>()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all because the wrong type of your property `studentsList`.
You should change your `studentsList` to type array that stores a list of dictionaries.

Also, this code below is totally wrong

```
//Assignment of studentsList and myStudentRoster
let myStudentRoster = ClassRosterModel()
studentsList = myStudentRoster.studentsRoster
```

I don't know what you are doing here. But you can't assign a Dictionary to an Array.